# How to setup SMTP setting in Canvas LMS?

Tags: canvas-lms, lti

I have installed **Canvas LMS** locally but I am stuck looking for SMTP settings. Could you please help me how to move ahead? I didn't find a UI screen to configure the settings.

Answer (score 0):

In your application in `config` directory you will find a file `outgoing_mail.yml` you have to provide like following configuration for SMTP setting:

```
development:
  address: smtp.gmail.com
  enable_starttls_auto: true
  port: "587"
  user_name: support@example.com
  password: ************
  authentication: "login" 
  domain: gmail.com
  outgoing_address: support@example.com
  default_name: Canvas


test:
  delivery_method: "test"

production:
  address: smtp.gmail.com
  enable_starttls_auto: true
  port: "587"
  user_name: support@example.com
  password: ************
  authentication: "login" 
  domain: gmail.com
  outgoing_address: support@example.com
  default_name: Canvas

# If receiving mail from multiple inboxes (see incoming_mail.yml.example),
# you'll want to include those addresses in a reply_to_addresses array so
# Canvas will select the Reply-To field of outgoing messages from all of the
# incoming mailboxes.

multiple_inboxes:
  address: smtp.gmail.com
  enable_starttls_auto: true
  port: "587"
  user_name: support@example.com
  password: ************
  authentication: "login" 
  domain: gmail.com
  outgoing_address: support@example.com
  default_name: Canvas
  reply_to_addresses:
  - "canvas1@example.com"
  - "canvas2@example.com"
  - "canvas3@example.com"
  - "canvas4@example.com"
```

Comment: PATH for outgoing_mail.yml file -> $CANVAS_ROOT/htdocs/config